# de-install orientdb community edition

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have **Orientdb Community Edition** working on my system and today I downloaded the **OrientDB Enterprise Edition** to try out for 45 days! So what do I need to do to run the Enterprise edition - how do I deinstall the community version and startup on the enterprise one on my system?

Thanks,
DBuserN

Answer (score 1):

You can:
- delete the folder where the community is installed OR
- keep community AND EE side by side in different folders

Be careful and don't run the community edition and EE at the same time.

If you need to move databases previously created, copy the folder of the database to the new installation. Do that with OrientDB server offline.

Comment: **Thanks  a lot Roberto!** I will try out in next few days and feel certain that it is going to work out!